# What are some different ways to handle warnings and errors in a programming language?

Tags: exception, warnings

I'm interested in the different ways warnings and errors are (and could be) handled in programming languages. As far as I know, the only language-level error/warning functionality are the following:

- compiler errors/warnings (which can be created by programmers using compiler commands, usually compiler specific)
- console errors that can be redirected to a file - eg stderr in C-like langauges
- throwable exception objects using explicit exception classes (like in java)
- simple string exceptions (like in php and javascript, e.g. throw("Dental error");

Are there other structures I haven't mentioned? What other kind of language-level functionality do you think should exist / could be useful?

My first through is to use exception-like structures for both, where an uncaught warning would be logged in a flat file (or brought up at compile-time if the compiler can prove it will happen). I can't decide whether its a good idea to force methods to explicitly handle exceptions, or if they should be allowed to "bubble up".

What error and warning handling structures and ideas are there out there?

Comment: Some languages have a distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions, make sure to include that in your taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **break to debugger**?